# how to disable a usercontrol during postback of an other control

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a  radcombobox, a usercontrol that works like a combobox and a button that generate a report.

The usercontrol was filled in based on selected value of radcombobox. The problem is that when the first combo selected changed and postback was appear, user can one of uc items before fill it on based new rdcombo selected item. And can click button that can clear error. I want disable the usercontrol and button during of postback.

my code is here :

```
  انتخاب نوع پرمیت:
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="cbbPermitType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblPermitType_SelectedIndexChanged"
        Width="300"  OnClientSelectedIndexChanging="OnClientSelectedIndexChangingHandler"  >
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
    <br />
    <br />

    انتخاب پرمیت:
    <br />

    <uc3:SimpleGridDown SearchMethod="HSEPermitEO" DisplayField1=" نوع پرمیت " DisplayField2="کد پرمیت"
        DisplayField3="نام مسئول انجام کار"  ID="sgdPermit"  Visible="true" runat="server" />


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function OnClientSelectedIndexChangingHandler(sender, eventArgs) {

     document.getElementById('sgdPermit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

</script>
```

My problem is that `getelementById('sgdPermit')` return `null`. And another is that disable property isn't exist.

if any one has any idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery modal or the jquery plug in for modal like [jquery blockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Comment: thanks for your help. but it works with timeout, i don't want set special time for wait, want to wait for durin postback.

Comment: actualy we can modified as we want.. when post back, call blockUI(); then when the postback finish call unblockUI()

Comment: you know .. i haven't any axperience in JQuery... could you please give me an example that shows how to do it. it can give me idea.